# Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: ios, изображения, xamarin, controller

Начинаю писать приложение под iOS в среде `Visual Studio for Mac`. Есть вёрстка нескольких экранов, на главном экране есть 4 картинки. Не получается создать переход между экранами по клику на них, так как вместо кнопки стоит изображение, а у него нет метода `TouchUpInside`. При клике на картинку должен происходить переход на соответствующий экран, как это сделать?

Comment: Жаль, вопрос закрыт. Для этих целей в iOS используется объект кнопки `UIButton` на который вешается изображение. [Пример на Obj-C тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1469487/5308802), можно легко перенести с Objective-C в Xamarin.

Comment: В obj-c можно и через изображение сделать переход повесив на него UITapGestureRecognizer , только надо еще isUserInteractionEnabled в true поставить (у UIImageView оно по умолчанию false). Насколько такой путь осуществим в xamarin не знаю, никогда им не пользовался

Comment: Спасибо за ответы всё пригодилось и получилась реализация через tapGesture повесил событие касания на картинку и сделал переход, ещё раз спасибо